# How to trigger css transition on specific time

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to trigger transition in javascript at 19:00:00 for example? 
And make it back in 08:00:00?

Day and night transition at 19:00:00 it will go from day to night and at 08:00:00 I need transition from night to day

**JavaScript**

```
const getTotalMinutes = ([hours, minutes]) =>
  (hours * 60) + minutes;

const transitionStart = getTotalMinutes([9, 11]);
const transitionEnd = getTotalMinutes([9, 10]);

const getCurrentTransitionState = () => {
  const now = new Date();
  const totalMinutes = getTotalMinutes([
    now.getHours(),
    now.getMinutes(),
  ]);

  const transitionTotal = transitionEnd - transitionStart;
  const timeIntoTransition = totalMinutes - transitionStart;

  if (timeIntoTransition >= transitionTotal) {
    return 1;
  }

  return timeIntoTransition > 0 ?
    timeIntoTransition / transitionTotal :
    0;
}

setInterval(() => {
  const current = getCurrentTransitionState();
  document.getElementById('day').style.opacity = 1 - current;
}, 1000);
```

**CSS**

```
img {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  height: 360px;
  width: 360px;
  transition: all 10s ease;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img id="night" src="../images/BackgroundDay.png" alt="My image" />
<img id="day" src="../images/BackgroundNight.png" alt="My image" />
```

I got only this transition in javascript. Can anyone help me please I am newbie... I have no idea how to make condition like that...

Comment: You want this to happen automatically if the browser was opened to your page prior to the designated time occurring or are you saying that you want the transition to happen as the user arrives at the page, based on the time at that moment?

Comment: It supposed to be background for web watch. So I have handled updating, cuz I have that in showTime function